# MVC project setup at the enterprise level. What's expected?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

By reading at several articles posted here, I get mismatched information about how to properly configure a project.

**I am looking for advise about how the pros do it at the enterprise level.**

I see different schools of though about this, some people design in a truly N-Tier fashion, others prefer to use EF Code First directly in the MVC application and have FAT models and sort of have one big MVC app with logical separation of concerns, etc.

So for a mid-size project this is my set up and I want to ask for your opinions about it.

**MVC application**

Models -- Here my models have just what the view needs, validation logic, etc. These models are designed to pass data between the controller and views only.

Controllers -- Call the service layer where business logic lives and gets domain models back if needed. Converts domain models into view models and vice-versa.

**Service layer**

This is were the business (domain) logic lives.
The service layer is also in charge of communicating with the data layer to perform CRUD operations. 
The service layer returns domain models to the controller in the MVC application and also expects domain models when invoked.

**Data Repository layer**

The data layer is a thin wrapper around EF and performs CRUD operations.
usually I will have a Code First approach where entity models are created for me by EF.
I convert the EF code first models to domain models and return these to the service layer.
The data layer also expect domain models from the service layer that in turn I convert to EF code first models and persist to the DB.

**Domain Model layer**

These are the domain models that are used and shared thorough the applications layers.

What's best design?
What's expected at the enterprise level?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing particularly wrong with the approach you've laid out. However, I do see it as overly complex. Your repository layer, in particular, is a totally unnecessary level of abstraction. You could simply just roll the EF stuff into your service layer and call it a day. Having to convert the entity into a domain model and then to a view model, is frankly, a pain. Just map your entity to your view model and back.

The only thing you should really bear in mind is that ASP.NET MVC *very* loosely follows the MVC pattern. There's no such thing as a true MVC *Model*, and trying to force something like an entity class into that mold is a huge mistake. Your *Model* is the combination and interaction of your entity class, view models that represent that class, and the querying logic you tuck away in your service layer.

Comment: Hi Chris; So you'll basically get rid of the domain model layer and add the EF to the service layer and use the EF Code First generated classes as your domain model?

Comment: Agreed. Patterns like MVC should be an inspiration or guidance, never a prescription. Do only what's necessary to deliver and maintain value.. anything else is waste. A pragmatic approach is usually helpful.

Comment: Abstraction for abstraction sake is an anti-pattern: remove the Repository wrapper unless it delivers net value (perceived value - complexity costs, etc) to you.

Comment: @IGIT: Yes, the entity *is* your domain. There's no need for a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to suggest have these layers in your project ----

**Entites Layer--** 
it should contains only all your poco classes in a model folder.Nothing else

**Data Layer----**
It should contain Db interactions logic.
Also your Dbcontext class should reside in this.
You may use Repository Pattern and unit of work pattern for better seperation of concern.Use dependency injection to resolve dependencies using Unity Container(there are many other container also available).Please have a look on these design pattern and container.there are many articles available on net for this.Simply go through them thoroughly.

**Service Layer ----**
It should contain only service methods to call into your controller as your controller should not directly talk to data Layer.Its a much better approach and prevent your business logic from being exposed to external attacks.

**MVC Layer or UI layer ---**
It should contain only the controllers whose work is to call services and business logics inside them.
and View folder where we have all the views to be shown to the end users.

Its a pretty big question.I hope may be u get some idea from this.

Comment: This is kind of what I have isn't it?